# Set type and parameters for generic class in runtime

Tags: c#

I have generic class `Wrapper<T>` . And I need set it parameters for constructor and type in runtime.
How set type for constructor without parameters I now:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Wrapper<>).MakeGenericType(obj.GetType()))
```

Help me set type and parameters. For example for constructor with two objects.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "set type and parameters". You've got code to obtain the appropriate `Type`... how you pass arguments to the constructor will then be the same whether or not it's a generic type. So I suggest you research that part, and then try to combine the two, showing a [mcve] with the problem if you get stuck.

Comment: Sorry, It is a little bit unclear. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CreateInstance(Type type, params object[] args)` overload:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Wrapper<>).MakeGenericType(obj.GetType()), param1, param2)
```

Comment: Thanks . It's work!)